# How to access data from my controller in a state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

What is the best way to stop a user from going to a state if there is no data for that state? I need to redirect the user to /featured if there is no data in one of the other states.

I thought that I could check the controller for data first and then redirect using $state.go if the data was null, but I can't find an example of how to access data in a controller inside of an onEnter event

I think a code example should sum it up:

```
fseControllers.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/featured");

  $stateProvider
    .state('featured', {
        url: "/featured",
        templateUrl: "featured-template"
    })

    .state('friends', {
        url: "/friends",
        templateUrl: "friends-template",
        controller: 'FseController',
        onEnter: function(){
            // Here I want to redirect to /featured if no data in controller
        }
    })

    .state('stories', {
        url: "/stories",
        templateUrl: "stories-template"
    })

    .state('events', {
        url: "/events",
        templateUrl: "events-template"
    })
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You could refactor your controller to use a service , that can be injected into onEnter function and to the Controller.
 [AngularJS Services](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services)

```
onEnter:function(FriendsService, $location){
  if(!!FriendsService.getFriends()){
    $location.path("/featured");
  }
}
```